# Error checking through Macro

Tags: c++, c, macros, compiler-errors

I want to compile a time error checking as mentioned below . But I am not able to find out how to use it inside `main()`?

```
#define BUILD_BUG_ON_ZERO(e) (sizeof(struct { int:-!!(e); }))
#define BUILD_BUG_ON_NULL(e) ((void *)sizeof(struct { int:-!!(e); }))
int main(){
BUILD_BUG_ON_NULL(12);
}
```

Below is the mentioned error

```
1--error C2332: 'struct' : missing tag name
2--error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '{'
3--error C2027: use of undefined type 'main::<unnamed-tag>'
4--error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
5--error C2059: syntax error : ')'
```

Can anyone please let me know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The width of a bitfield must be an integer constant expression. `val` isn't one. So that won't work.

Comment: When compiling with gcc-4.2, an error is issued `bitfield.c:5: error: bit-field ‘<anonymous>’ width not an integer constant`.

Comment: @DanielFischer:: I have edited the question with the constant value . But still its showing the same error .

Comment: @Learner This is a C macro, you should not use it with a C++ compiler.

Comment: You'll get better help if you explain what you're trying to ... "go for a compile time error checking" (which is not grammatical English) doesn't cut it.

Comment: Before you go any further you need to pick a single language. You need to decide to use either C or C++ and be clear about that choice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First the macros `BUILD_BUG_ON_ZERO` and `BUILD_BUG_ON_NULL` trigger a compilation error if their argument is *different than* `0`.

If the macro argument is `0`, they will not trigger any compilation error but yield a `0` for `BUILD_BUG_ON_ZERO` and a `(void *) 0` for `BUILD_BUG_ON_NULL`

These macros comes from the Linux kernel which is written in C and they are only working for C programs.

In C++ these macros are *not* working. The reason is in C++ you cannot declare a structure in a `sizeof` expression.

You don't mention in your question if you are compiling your program in C or in C++, but I strongly suspect you are compiling it in C++. So don't use these macros in C++.

Comment: Yes i am using c++ compiler . Thanks . Now i got the solution that it cant be used inside c++ since there is no provision of declaring a type inside the sizeof expression ..

Comment: Eh, BUILD_BUG_ON_ZERO surely should indicate that there is an error when the value is zero. Hence the !! to make non-zero values negative and get an error.

Comment: @MatsPetersson You should read again the macro definition: compilation error is done when the macro argument is non-zero. The `!!` idiom is used to normalize the boolean argument: `0` goes to `0` and non-zero goes to `1`. The idea behind the name of these macros is all `BUILD_BUG_ON*` macros trigger a compilation error when the argument is true. The suffix `ZERO` has nothing to do with the condition but with the value yielded if the macro argument is false. Anyway I find the names of these macros misleading.

Comment: Ok, yes, you're right. Too early in the morning... ;) I was thinking of the Linux macros, which is definitely BUG_ON(truthvalue) - if the truthvalue is true, then it stops teh kernel.

Answer (score 6):

**EDIT**: the question was originally tagged as C++, but now as just C.

I'm not going to chase further fundamental changes of the question.

Original answer for the C++ tagged question:

---

This source code:

```
#define BUILD_BUG_ON_ZERO(e) (sizeof(struct { int:-!!(e); }))
#define BUILD_BUG_ON_NULL(e) ((void *)sizeof(struct { int:-!!(e); }))
int main(){
BUILD_BUG_ON_NULL(0);
}
```

compiled with g++ 4.7.1., produced

```
foo.cpp: In function 'int main()':
foo.cpp:4:1: error: types may not be defined in 'sizeof' expressions
foo.cpp:4:21: warning: statement has no effect [-Wunused-value]
```

Which says directly what’s wrong.

So it is a good idea to compile with different compilers.

---

Possibly you’re looking for **compile time assertions**.

With C++11 you can use `static_assert`, e.g. via a macro such as

```
#define STATIC_ASSERT( e ) static_assert( e, #e )
```

In C++03 you could implement it as a valid/invalid `typedef`, because a `typedef` can be repeated in the same translation unit, and can be used in a class definition:

```
#define STATIC_ASSERT( e ) typedef char staticAssert_shouldBeTrue[e? 1 : -1]
```

One problem with that was that g++ had/has a compiler bug, where a repeated `typedef` is not always accepted as it should be, necessitating generation of a locally unique name for each one, e.g. by using `__LINE__`.

But you can always just use the definition in the Boost library, since Boost supports most extant compilers with special-casing for each one as necessary.

Comment: so you are telling we cant make compile time assertion with the above mentioned idea as types has been defined inside sizeof() expression ?

Comment: @Learner: C and C++ are *different* languages. the above is an answer for C++. your question is right now tagged as only C.

Answer (score 2):

Compiling with `gcc -std=c99 -pedantic-errors`, I get

```
screwed.c: In function ‘main’:
screwed.c:5:1: error: negative width in bit-field ‘<anonymous>’
screwed.c:5:1: error: struct has no named members [-pedantic]
```

and those are the errors the compilation should give when the code is compiled as C. The width of a bit-field must be non-negative (positive if it has a name), and a `struct` must have at least one named member (two, if the last one is a flexible array member). `struct`s without tags are allowed.

You either compiled the code not as C, or your compiler is non-conforming.

When compiling as C++, the additional error

```
error: types may not be defined in ‘sizeof’ expressions
```

is generated (but the one about the `struct` without named members disappears).

In C++, you may not define type in a `sizeof` expression, and your compiler chose a less clear way of telling you.

Comment: so you are telling the above way is not the right way to check for compile time errors  ?

Comment: @Learner add the lines `#ifdef __cplusplus #error C++ compiler used  #endif` to your program to check you are not using a C++ compiler.

Comment: Well, what are you trying to detect at compile time? Since the argument of your macro must be a constant expression, it is fairly limited. You can make it compile even in very strict mode when the argument is `0` by adding a named member to the `struct`, you will get the "negative width" error for non-zero arguments. If you use only one `!`, the cases are switched.

Comment: @ouah That should be at the top of _every_ source file ;)